# iPhone Application Should Close, not go to Background

Tags: iphone, multitasking

I have an application wherein when the user taps iPhone's central button, the application is sent to background, but I want it to be closed.

I can hand event and close it, but may be there is some configuration setting to deny running in the background?

Thank you

Answer (score 12):

If you want your app to terminate when the user presses the home button, set the value of `UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend` to `YES` in your app's `Info.plist` file. If you do this, when the user taps the home button the `applicationWillTerminate:` method of your app delegate will be called and then your application will terminate.