# How to make iPhone app not resume, and just launch fresh every time?

Tags: iphone, xcode, cordova

I used Phonegap to create a simple webpage as an iPhone app. I'm using the latest version of XCode and iOS SDK 4.1 to make this, and the latest version of Phonegap as of today.

I want my iPhone app to always launch fresh, not resume, every time the user taps the icon on their home screen. Is there any easy way to set this, or is it not too complicated? I have no experience with XCode or Objective-C, just HTML/CSS/Jquery etc.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone Application Should Close, not go to Background](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3983154/iphone-application-should-close-not-go-to-background)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's easy. You just need to have your app opt out of being suspended when the home button is pressed. Once you do that, it will be terminated when the home button is pressed and relaunch "fresh" every time.

Details are here: [iPhone Application Should Close, not go to Background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3983154/iphone-application-should-close-not-go-to-background/3983176#3983176)

Comment: Thank you that was very easy. No coding required. Thanks again.